# Pandas print string based on condition in seperate dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a separate pandas dataframe of strings only based upon a condition for each row in my data.

Ill try to make up some data in a pandas dataframe:

```
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd

# Create a df with a date-time index with data every 6 hours
rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=5, freq='6H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 15, 5)}, index=rng)

df
```

What I would like to do in this separate pandas dataframe column is if the data point is greater than 10, print 'too hot' or if the data point is less than 5 print 'too cool' else print 'just right.' So for each row in the data there should be print output in a separate dataframe.

I know this function isn't right because I dont want to look at `.any()` or `.all()`

```
x = df

def OUTput(x):
    if df.any() > 10:
        print('Too hot.')
    elif df.any() < 5:
        print('Too cool.')
    else:
        print('Normal.')

OUTput(x)
```

And the only way that I could think of to create this separate dataframe would be in a `df.apply()` but I am not sure if this is the best practice or not. This only gives me an error, ***The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().***

```
df['PrintOut'] = df['Random_Number'].apply(OUTput(x))

df
```

Comment: This is very confusing. Print in a different column? Are you sure you don't want a simple string (and in that case you are looking for np.where())

Comment: Can `np.where()` really produce his desired output? I know `where` can handle an if/else situation, but not sure how handle an if/elif/else condition. I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `apply` on a `pandas.core.series.Series`, which is what you have when you slice a column of the DataFrame (like this: `df['Random_Number']`), then each value of the series is passed to the function you are applying.

Try this:

```
def OUTput(x):
    if x > 10:
        return 'Too hot.'
    elif x < 5:
        return 'Too cool.'
    else:
        return 'Normal.'

df['PrintOut'] = df['Random_Number'].apply(OUTput)
df
```

Also notice that I changed your `OUTput` function substantially. I changed it to use the parameter `x` instead of the global `df`, and instead of calling print (which returns `None`) I return the string so that it gets put in the new `PrintOut` column of the DataFrame.

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

```
                     Random_Number   PrintOut
2018-01-05 00:00:00             13   Too hot.
2018-01-05 06:00:00              2  Too cool.
2018-01-05 12:00:00             13   Too hot.
2018-01-05 18:00:00              5    Normal.
2018-01-06 00:00:00             10    Normal.
```